# How can I disable the use of the __MigrationHistory table in Entity Framework 4.3 Code First?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using Entity Framework 4.3 Code First with a custom database initializer like this:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MyContextInitializer());
    }
}

public class MyContextInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
    {
        // Add defaults to certain tables in the database

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

Whenever my model changes, I edit my POCO's and mappings manually and I update my database manually.

When I run my application again, I get this error:

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> #### The model backing the 'MyContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.InvalidOperationException: The model backing the 'MyContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

Using EFProfiler, I also notice these queries being executed:

```
-- statement #1
SELECT [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM   (SELECT COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM   [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]) AS [GroupBy1]

-- statement #2
SELECT TOP (1) [Project1].[C1]          AS [C1],
               [Project1].[MigrationId] AS [MigrationId],
               [Project1].[Model]       AS [Model]
FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[MigrationId] AS [MigrationId],
               [Extent1].[CreatedOn]   AS [CreatedOn],
               [Extent1].[Model]       AS [Model],
               1                       AS [C1]
        FROM   [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]) AS [Project1]
ORDER  BY [Project1].[CreatedOn] DESC
```

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At first I was sure it was because you set the default initializer in the ctor but investigating a bit I found that the initializer isn't run when the context is created but rather when you query/add something for the first time.

The provided initializer all check model compability so you are out of luck with them. You can easily make your own initializer like this instead though:

```
 public class Initializer : IDatabaseInitializer<Context>
    {

        public void InitializeDatabase(Context context)
        {
            if (!context.Database.Exists())
            {
                context.Database.Create();
                Seed(context);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        private void Seed(Context context)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

That shouldn't check compability and if the Database is missing it will create it.

UPDATE: "Context" should be the type of your implementation of DbContext

Comment: Thanks, Mikael. Your solution seems to work. Are you positive the default `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` does nothing more than `if (!context.Database.Exists()) { context.Database.Create(); Seed(context); }`?

Comment: I'm not sure but in the case where no db exists they generate exactly the same sql according to Sql Profiler atleast.

Comment: I have just decompiled EntityFramework.dll to see what it does. Take a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/3017384 The most important missing part is `context.SaveChanges();` after calling `Seed(context);`. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Ahh, I see. I would likely have put the SaveChanges in the Seed method but this is better as it is compatible if they ever change the default behaviour and you want to change back to inheritence

Comment: Should 'Context' in this solution not be DbContext?  When I pulled this into my solution the only Context that is found is in the System.Remoting.Contexts namespace.  If I change these to DbContext everything looks correct.

Comment: Jeremy, Context should be your DbContext implementation (The class where you have your DbSets).

Comment: @MikaelEliasson Ah, that makes sense.  Thanks.  We will never use the create DB part of this initializer so we're just going with using DbContext and it seems to work at supressing querying of __MigrationHistory.

Answer (score 0):

Pass null to `System.Data.Entity.Database`'s

```
public static void SetInitializer<TContext>(
    IDatabaseInitializer<TContext> strategy
)
where TContext : DbContext
```

to disable initialization for your context. Don't implement `IDatabaseInitializer` to disable it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.setinitializer(v=vs.113).aspx