# Asp.net mvc EF code first doesn't create tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Where does EF code first create some tables? I manually deleted some of them using SSMS because I wanted to add one column to them. But now EF doesn't create these tables and it throws an exception like "Invalid object name ...". I also can't lose data from the tables that I don't remove. Any idea what can I do to fix this problem? I am crazy from this exception already.

Comment: Delete the database and try again?

Comment: You will need to drop the entire table that you modified and re add this table.

Comment: add a migration instead. EF won't check that the schema is correct, but rather check whether the __MigrationHistory entry checksum is correct.

Comment: I agree with @DevilSuichiro: you should be able to fix this with a migration. Since it's a delete it's easier than adding some PK and indexes because then the names must match. Remember that with the code first approach, you shouldn't alter the db with ssms.

Comment: If the project just started, delete the database then try again. otherwise create a migration.

Comment: Any good tutorial or some guide how to make this migration? A have no experience with this. Thanks.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259079/how-can-i-disable-the-use-of-the-migrationhistory-table-in-entity-framework-4